# bash trap DEBGU messed up _ underscore variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

_ is a special variable in bash, it can expand to the last argument to the previous command,
but if I put `trap 'echo $BASH_COMMAND > /dev/null' DEBUG` in bash, _ can't expand to the last argument to the previous command, well why?

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) reads:

> Subsequently, expands to the last argument to the previous simple
> command executed in the foreground, after expansion.

In a sense, it **does** expand to the last argument. Try the following:

```sh
trap 'ls' DEBUG
echo $_
```

This actually executes `ls` and shows you the output. I assume `$_` executed the argument and gave you the output, however `echo $BASH_COMMAND > /dev/null` redirects its output to `/dev/null` that's why the output of `echo $_` is empty. Try redirecting to a file and see if `echo $_` creates the file.

```sh
trap 'echo $BASH_COMMAND > /tmp/test.txt' DEBUG
ls -l /tmp/test.txt
echo $_
ls -l /tmp/test.txt
```